# Removing Bootstrap 4 DataTable Scrollbar Results in Narrower Table

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, datatables, spacing

I have some tables that, when converted to Bootstrap data tables, result in a horizontal scroll bar appearing below the table.

Assigning the table's div a "p-3" class to add padding removes the horizontal scroll bar but also makes the table narrower.

Is there a way to accomplish removing the scroll bar without reducing the horizontal space used by the table?

Comment: can you show the screenshot of how it is looking now for others on SO community to understand better?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it easily with the overflow property.
use `overflow:hidden;` or `overflow-x:hidden;`